# object oriented programming with web parsing in python

Tags: python, class, object, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am teaching myself object oriented programming and web parsing in python. I want to create a class that will parse a web page. I have a problem and a question about my code.

I am trying to download a page using Beautifulsoup. I created a class and a function to download the page but the page doesn't seem to download. I'm not sure why. If someone could help me with this, that would be great. Here is the code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

class parser():

    def __init__(self, url):
                self.url = "http://www.any_url"
                self.contents  = ''
                
        def download_page(self):
            
                page=urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

                page_find=soup.findAll()
                print page_find

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser.download_page
```

Another issue I had was the indents. Right now, it appears my function download_page exists inside my constructor. I tried to keep my functions separate but I kept getting errors because of my indents.  I basically just kept hitting 'tab' until it all compiled. Could someone explain why this is happening? Is it really a problem?

I ask because whenever I looked at object oriented in python, functions are usually indented more evenly.

Comment: Set your editor to expand tabs to spaces and set the tab width to 4. See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you aren't using classes correctly. Try something like:

```
class Parser(object):
 
    def __init__(self, url):
        ...

    def download_page(self):
        ...
```

Then use:

```
parser = Parser(url) # create instance of the class
parser.download_page() # call instance method
```

At the moment, you are trying to call `download_page` on the class, not an instance.

That said, when you have a class with *"two methods, one of which is `__init__`"* you should probably [stop writing classes](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html).

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work. Except now my indents are even further out, but whatever.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python, I don't think that your current approach is very healthy!

Comment: I edited my code above. I know indentation is important that's why I'm asking. For some reason, my code won't compile without the additional indents. And I am at a loss why. Do you have any information as to why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like you have a mix of tabs and spaces - switch to [all spaces](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).